# Using the mean value theorem calculate this limit : $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{arctan(x^2+x-1)+\frac{\pi}{4}}{x^2+3x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Using the mean value theorem calculate this limit :
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\arctan(x^2+x-1)+\frac{\pi}{4}}{x^2+3x}$$

I tried to apply Mean value theorem on $\arctan(x^2+x-1)$ but i didn't find the good result

Comment: Can you show what you did?

Comment: I tried to use mean value theorem on $[0,x]$ on the function $arctan(x^2+x-1)$ but i find something which don't help to find the result

Comment: You're trying to find the limit as x approaches 0... but what exactly happens when x=0? Your quotient becomes $\frac{0}{0}$.... so apply L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: I mentioned i the topic to apply mean value theorem

Comment: We can extend the MVT to L'Hopitals. By the Mean Value Theorem $\exists c \in (c,c+h)$ such that $\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = \frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{g(c+h) - g(c)} = \frac{f(c+h)}{g(c+h)}...$ so now note that $f(c) = 0, g(c) = 0$. Then let $h \to 0^+$, so that $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(c+h)}{g(c+h)} = \lim_{x \to c^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ =  $\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
\arctan (x^2+x-1) + \frac{\pi}{4} = \arctan (-1+x+x^2)-\arctan(-1).
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\arctan (x^2+x-1) + \frac{\pi}{4}}{x^2+3x} &= \frac{\arctan (-1+x+x^2)-\arctan(-1)}{x^2+3x} \\
&= \frac{\arctan (-1+x+x^2)-\arctan(-1)}{x+x^2} \frac{x+x^2}{x^2+3x} \\
&\to \left( D \arctan (-1) \right) \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}
\end{align}
$$
as $x \to 0$, due to the definition of the derivative. Here $D$ denotes differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

With $f(x)=\arctan(x^2+x-1)$, you want to find:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^2+3x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}}{x+3}$$
The Mean Value Theorem gives you a $c \in (0,x)$ such that:
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'(c)$$
which means you also have:
$$f_m'(x) \le \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} \le f_M'(x)$$
with $f_m'(x)$ the minimal value of $f'$ on $[0,x]$ and $f_M'(b)$ the maximal value.

The limit then follows by squeezing since:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f_m'(x)}{x+3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f_M'(x)}{x+3} = \frac{1}{6}$$